# Crear un objeto a traves de un array de datos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Hola a todos en esta ocasión acudo a ustedes por lo siguiente, quiero crear un objeto en JS con datos que me llegan de un array, el array contiene los siguientes datos:

```
const columnsTable = [
  "id",
  "nombre",
  "edad"
];
```

El array de odjetos que quiero crear con el array anterior, tiene que tener la siguiente estructura:

```
 columns: [
        {
          name: 'id', align: 'center', label: 'id', field: 'id'
        },
        {
          name: 'nombre', align: 'center', label: 'nombre', field: 'nombre'
        },
        {
          name: 'edad', align: 'center', label: 'edad', field: 'edad'
        }
      ]
    }
```

Donde cada objeto representado en el array de objetos tiene un valor del array columsTable en name, label y field.

Estoy intentando de la siguiente manera pero no logro tener exito:

```js
var columnsTable = [
  "id",
  "nombre",
  "edad",
];

var colums = [];

columnsTable.forEach((columna) => {
        this.colums.push({ name: columna, align: 'center', label: columna, field: columna });
        console.log(colums);
});
```

Ya que este al final me retorna todos los valores de mi array dentro de una propiedad de mi objeto.
Desde ya les doy las gracias, cualquier aporte me seria de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entonces espero que esto te ayude y sea lo que buscas.

**Ejemplo:**

```js
var types = [
  ["id", "nombre", "edad"],
  ["id", "nombre", "edad"],
  ["id", "nombre", "edad"]
];
var colums = [];

types.forEach((key) => {
    colums.push({
      name: key[0],
      aling: "center",
      label: key[1],
      field: key[2],
    })
});

console.log(colums)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de como acceder a los datos de un array que contiene objetos.

Espero haberte ayudado!

**Ejemplo:**

```js
let arrayObject = [{ // array con contenido Object
    name: "Carlos",
    apellido: "Santos"
  },
  {
    name: "Martín",
    apellido: "Gutierrez"
  }
]

arrayObject.forEach(key => { // accedo al array
  console.log("nombre: "+key.name, "\n", "apellido: "+key.apellido)
});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte Daniel, sin embargo no es lo que busco, sigo en eso en cuanto lo logre comparto mi respuesta.